# Reading from streams instead of files in spring batch itemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I am getting a csv file as a webservice call which needs to be laoded. Right now I am saving it in temp directory to provide it as setResource to Reader.

Is there a way to provide stream(byte[]) as is instead of saving the file first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method `setResource` of the `ItemReader` takes a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` as a parameter. This class has a few out-of-the-box implementations, among which you can find `org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource`. This class' constructor takes a `java.io.InputStream` which can be implemented by `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`.

So technically, yes you can consume a `byte[]` parameter in an `ItemReader`.

Now, for how to actually do that, here are a few ideas :

1. Create your own `FlatFileItemReader` (since CSV is a flat file) and make it implement `StepExecutionListener`

   public class CustomFlatFileItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader implements StepExecutionListener {
   }
2. Override the `beforeStep` method, do your webservice call within and save the result in a variable

   private byte[] stream;

   @Override
   public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

   ```java
     // your webservice logic
     stream = yourWebservice.results();
   ```

   }
3. Override the `setResource` method to pass this `stream` as the actual resource.

   @Override
   public void setResource(Resource resource) {

   ```java
    // Convert byte array to input stream
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream);

    // Create springbatch input stream resource
    InputStreamResource res = new InputStreamResource(is);

    // Set resource
    super.setResource(res);
   ```

   }

Also, if you don't want to call your webservice within the ItemReader, you can simply store the byte array in the `JobExecutionContext` and get it in the `beforeStep` method with `stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("key");`

Comment: Is there a way to pass a stream while launching the job through job Launcher, something similar to passing jobParameters? I have a separate service for getting file and then I want to initiate the batch job to load it.

Comment: @explorer Unfortunately, `JobParameters` can only pass `String`, `Long`, `Date`, and `Double` type. According to this post : http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/96660-how-to-pass-complex-objects-to-job-launcher, you have to either use external storage (save your file) or declare a bean which could provide access to it.

Comment: Thank you @Thrax. I also noted that and was looking for some work around which seems tricky...
https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-966

Answer (score 0):

I am doing right now with FlaFileItemReader, reading a file from Google Storage. No needed to extends:

```
    @Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<MyDTO> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filename']}") String filename) {
    
    InputStream stream = googleStorageService.getInputStream(GoogleStorage.UPLOADS, filename);
    
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MyDTO>()
            .name("myItemReader")
            .resource(new InputStreamResource(stream)) //InputStream here
            .delimited()
            .names(FIELDS)
            .lineMapper(lineMapper()) // Here is mapped like a normal File
            .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MyDTO>() {{
                setTargetType(MyDTO.class);
            }})
            .build();
}
```